# Orthonormal basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

For $n=2$, find an orthonormal basis of the subspace spanned by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

--Do I simply use Gram-Schmidt while treating each of the four columns as the vectors, or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Do they define in your textbook what they mean when they say that two $2\times 2$ matrices are orthogonal to each other?  That is, is there an inner product that they define for matrices?  The only thing I can think of is that they'd want you to treat these as column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way in which an inner product is defined on the space of $n \times n$ square matrices is $\langle A, B \rangle = trace(A^tB)$. Use Gram-Schmidt using this inner product.